# Flash Pro on device debugging via USB with an iOS device possible?

Tags: ios, flash, air, remote-debugging

I use Flash Pro CS6 and AIR. Is it possible to do on device debugging via USB with an iOS device? Or is the only way do accomplish that is with a command line? I understand that Flash Pro CS6 offers debugging via USB on Android. Why not on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful:
Debugging AIR applications over USB on iOS
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/06/13/debugging-air-applications-over-usb-on-ios/

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be what I was looking for.